# Why is this 11 class selector less specific than the ID?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

```
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.one.two.three.four.five.six.seven.eight.nine.ten.eleven {
  background-color: #f00;
}


<div id="box" class="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven"></div>
```

If the following points are given to each type of selector, then how come the above class selector does not override the ID selector?

Style attribute: 1,0,0,0
ID: 0,1,0,0
Class, pseudo-class, attribute selector: 0,0,1,0
Element: 0,0,0,1

Comment: No matter how many classes you have, it's still: class < ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the **[CSS specificity point system](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** is exactly as you have specified:

- Style attribute: `1,0,0,0`
- ID: `0,1,0,0`
- Class, pseudo-class, attribute selector: `0,0,1,0`
- Element: `0,0,0,1`

[image: Specificity]

> The commas are there to remind us that this isn't really a "base 10" system, in that you could technically have a specificity value of like 0,1,13,4 - and that "13" doesn't spill over like a base 10 system would.

Your ID selector is `0,1,0,0`, and your combined class selector is `0,0,11,0`.

At no point will any combination of class selectors **ever** override a single ID selectors, as is seen in the following:

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0; /* yellow */
}

.one.two.three.four.five.six.seven.eight.nine.ten.eleven {
  background-color: #f00; /* red */
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven"></div>
```

Comment: i guess he's aware about this, no ? here already added the points in his question

Comment: OP asks "*If the following points are given to each type of selector, then how come the above class selector does not override the ID selector?*". The answer is because it's not a base 10 system, and the points don't 'spill over'. Thus, more than 10 classes don't override a single ID.

Comment: That quote is really the answer to OP's question: It's not base 10 calculations, `10 classes != 1 ID`.

Comment: Thanks @ObsidianAge, that makes it a little clearer, but I don't quite get why the combined class selector is 0,0,11,0?

Comment: @bernk elevent classes == 1 + 1 +1 ... +1 = 11

Comment: Oh! I understand what Obsidian Age meant now. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

As commented/answered above, ID will always win but here is a trick to make your classes win.

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.one.two.three.four.five.six.seven.eight.nine.ten.eleven:not(#random_id) {
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven"></div>
```

**Why this works when we know that pseudo-classes are less specific than ID?**

Simply because The `:not()` itself **doesn't add anything to the specificity number as other pseudo-classes do**. However, the selectors **within** the `:not()` do.<sup>[ref](https://bitsofco.de/on-not-and-specificity/)</sup>

So it's like i added an ID to my class selectors.

Comment: Or just use `!important`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes but since it's about specifity and points i wanted to share a trick that allow the last one to be more specific considering points.

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you please explain why this works?

Comment: @bernk i added an explanation ;)