# Universal Selector with Descendent Selector Specificity

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have a generic layout component that needs to lay out its children with a vertical space between them:

```
.container > * + * {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

For reasons I won't go into, I can't guarantee the order the component styles are loaded in.

If a child component has had a reset to its margins applied, for example …

```
.child {
  margin: 0
}
```

… and it is loaded after the `.container` css, its styled will win out because a wildcard selector has no specificity, meaning both declarations are of equal weight (so the last declaration will win).

I don't want the container to know or care about what its children are (and I don't want to add a specific class to all the children).

**Is there any way to increase the specificity of the first selector while leaving it generic (so it applies to any children).**

Comment: use `not()` like this `.container:not(#random_ID) > * + *` related https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633333/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742059/8620333

Comment: @Temani Afif: An ID is overkill. A simple type selector will suffice: `.container:not(_) > * + *`

Comment: @BoltClock true. I was more about thinking of a selector that will beat any other selector even with mutiple class,pseuo class.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - If that's the goal, then this is exactly what `!important` is *for*. For all the concern that `!important` is the nuclear option, given the tight restriction of the selector, and the minimal declaration set, it's a pretty surgical strike.

Comment: @Alohci indeed. I think we all are moving around and forgetting about `!important` which is the trivial and logical solution here.

Comment: @Temani Afif: Rereading the question, you're probably right. An ID, or !important, may not be so overkill after all.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant alternative (i.e. one that comes with the additional specificity you need without requiring specificity hacks) is

```
.container > :not(:first-child)
```

which is functionally equivalent to your original selector, with a specificity of (0, 2, 0) over the original's (0, 1, 0).

```css
.container {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

/* 1 class, 1 pseudo-class -> specificity = (0, 2, 0) */
.container > :not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

/* 1 class                 -> specificity = (0, 1, 0) */
.child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yet another pseudo-class-based alternative, albeit somewhat less elegant since its meaning is not spelled out in plain English as is the case with the one in my answer, is `.container > :nth-child(n+2)`

Answer (score 1):

By adding the selector

```
.container > * + [class]
```

You can get a more specific selector it seems for the margin rule.

You can also use the :not() rule as suggested by [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)

```css
.container, .container2, .container3 {
   background-color: goldenrod;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: block;
   margin-bottom:50px;
}

.container > * + * {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.container2 > * + *,
.container2 > * + [class] {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.container3:not(#doyoudreamofelectricsheep) > * + * {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}


.child {
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:red;
  color: black;
  
}

.foobar {
  height: 20px;
  background-color:black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
Without the "fix"
<section class="container2">
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       child
   </div>
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       child
   </div>
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class>
       just class
   </div>
</section>

With the [class] "fix"
<section class="container2">
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       child
   </div>
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       child
   </div>
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class>
       just class
   </div>
</section>

With the :not(#doyoudreamofelectricsheep) "fix"
<section class="container3">
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       child
   </div>
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       child
   </div>
   <div class="foobar">
       foobar
   </div>
   <div class>
       just class
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting - you are using a 'class' attribute selector with no value. I wonder what the browser support is like for that. Seems like something a browser might choose to ignore.

Comment: No, they should all just obey it. The class attribute is something that is present or not. So it would ignore `<div><div>` but it would catch `<div class><div>` it's valid css. This way you can also select for `<div data-some-custom-attribute>` with `[data-some-custom-attribute] {color: red;}`. I use it constantly and all mobile browsers and desktop browsers i've tested in, even the old ones support this. I added an example in the snippet.

Comment: OK. So it acts as a switch. That makes sense. I guess the only disadvantage with your approach is that it requires the child to have at least one class, but that's pretty much a given.

Comment: you can also use the :not() hack. it really is up to you and the rest of your codebase what will help more ensuring you get the correct selector. Also, you notice I implemented the dual selection with the comma separating the two conditions for matching. `.container > * + *, .container * + [class]` which means it selects those without and with class.